# Sirikit - Is there a way siri can allow us to customize the talkback

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

I am trying to implement an airlines app which will talkback in text and return miles for the users. I am using `INSearchForAccountsIntentHandling` protocol to implement it.

Like I want siri to reply saying "Your miles for the account no: 1000211 is 3000" in text on the screen of siri. I didnt find any documentation online on how to do it.

Firstly, is it even possible to do that ?

Secondly if it is, how can I implement it in my method below:

`func handle(intent: INSearchForAccountsIntent, completion: @escaping (INSearchForAccountsIntentResponse) -> Void) {
  print("Sirikit is working")
}`

Comment: Were you able to figure out this?

Comment: Apple doesnt have the API as of right now to handle the scenario I am trying to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're hoping to use this for, it seems you don't want `SiriKit`, but rather the use of `AVSpeechSynthesizer`.  If you simply want your app to read back your sentence to the user the most basic implementation would look like this:

```
import AVFoundation

let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Your miles for the account no: 1000211 is 3000")
synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

I think you'd need to adjust the way you're forming sentences to remove abbreviations, but as a concept this totally works.

Check out [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/speech_synthesis) for much more info and details.

Comment: Not exactly what I want. I think Siri cannot do talk back for what I am looking for.
Thanks for the help though.

Comment: But on that note, I want to do something like Robinhood which shows the UI if I ask the question to Siri which is totally a different question.